# Catalyst Adding LDAP Authentication

Tags: perl, authentication, ldap, catalyst

I have a Catalyst application that I recently created. I based the original authentication model on the example given in the Catalyst example using "SimpleDB". I am also using the Authorization::Roles module to permission users in specific application roles.

Now I need to move to LDAP authentication. I need to use LDAP to authenticate the user, but the user should still have a row in the User table to validate that the user is allowed to use the application. Also, the application should still lookup the User Roles from the Role table to determine what roles the user is allowed.

My question is: I have read that dropping in the Catalyst LDAP authentication module is pretty much Plug-N-Play, but will the application still use the User/Role tables that are already defined in the application?

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I need to do the role part, but haven't found a good way to get roles from somewhere else than the authentication realm.